# Creating a Matrix using 2 columns of a dataframe and count the No of occurrences of events

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a Df which looks like this:-

```
    tests machine
    A     mac1
    A     mac1
    A     mac2
    A     mac2
    B     mac1
    B     mac1
    B     mac3
    C     mac3
    C     mac3
```

Using this Df i want create a Dataframe which looks like this:

```
    No_of_tests   mac1 mac2 mac3
    A             2    2    0     #test A is done 2 times on mac1, 2 times on mac2 and so on
    B             2    1    0     #test B is done 2 times on mac1, 1 time on mac2 and so on
    C             0    0    2     #test C is done 0 times on mac1, 0 times on mac2 and so on
```

Can somebody help me create this matrix using the Dataframe above.

Comment: `pd.crosstab(df.tests,df.machine,df.machine,aggfunc='count')`

Comment: I am getting all the values NAN's after using this @Datanovice

Comment: I think the NAN's representing 0's meaning that test is not performed in that machine?

Comment: you'll get `nan` for non matches use `fillna(0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IICU

```
 df.groupby('tests')['machine'].value_counts().unstack('machine', fill_value=0).reset_index()
```

[image]